# Ubuntu seems to not work with Lenovo Y700 even in Legacy Mode

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, lenovo

I have been trying for days to dual boot Linux and Win 8.1 with a Live CD install. I have tried Ubuntu, Fedora, OpenSUSE, CentOS, and Arch Linux. All installs either Failed, Froze, or Wouldn't start due to reading partitions wrong or not at all.

I made sure Secure boot, fast boot, Intel TPP was turned off.

I reinstalled Win 8.1 in Legacy Mode because I got tired of dealing with UEFI.
And when trying to install Ubuntu, it either freezes at the 5 dots or freezes in the begging if the install at the Partitioning part.

Fedora will allow me to boot the Live CD with the basic graphics get to the partitioning part but won't allow me to create the mount points and keeps saying I need to set /boot/efi even though I am on Legacy.

I tried a frugal install with unetbootin and Ubuntu still just freezes at the five dots. It seems that Linux can not work on this Laptop.

Specs:

- Lenovo Y700
- i7 -6700HQ
- RAM 8GB
- BIOS ( UEFI Turned Off)
- NVIDIA® GeForce GTX 960M 2GB
- 1TB HD (partitioned to around 600 & 300)
- Win 8.1 Enterprise (Used Win 8.1 Pro before re-intall)

Is there anyway to get Ubuntu or any other linux distro installed?

After trying 16.04 I get this error:

"This machine's firmware has started the installer in UEFI mode but it
looks like there may be existing operating systems already installed using
"BIOS compatibility mode". If you continue to install Debian in UEFI mode,
it might be difficult to reboot the machine into any BIOS-mode operating
systems later.

If you wish to install in UEFI mode and don't care about keeping the
ability to boot one of the existing systems, you have the option to force
that here. If you wish to keep the option to boot an existing operating
system, you should choose NOT to force UEFI installation here."

Windows 8.1 is installed in Legacy Mode, so I can't force install on UEFI and I can't turn UEFI On. Which doesn't make sense to do anyway since everything is set to Legacy.

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured it out. This is all done with Bios is Legacy mode, secure boot turned off, and Legacy 1st in boot order.

1. Win 7 Usb installer to create a no UEFI install( others like Rufus and unetbootin create UFEI ones.
   microsoft.com/en-us/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool
2. Reinstall Win 8.1 and during the install delete all partitions
3. Shrink the Windows HD ( use disk manger or other software)
4. Run unetbootin Frugal install on Win 8.1 and install Ubuntu 16.04 to your internal HD (not to a USB)
   http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1801434
   https://sourceforge.net/p/unetbootin/wiki/installmodes/
5. Reboot and wait for Bootloader to show up and slect Unetbootin
6. Install Ubuntu or Live CD
7. Reboot into into Win 8.1 and uninstall unetbootin

   I don't know why usb installs for Linux are not working, but for windows it is. But unetbootin frugal isntall really helped

Comment: Can u please explain what you mean by "usb installs for Linux are not working"

Answer (score 1):

I got a lenovo y700 also. I needed the 4.4 kernel before i worked so i installed ubuntu 16.04 without any problem after i ofc disable fast boot. Secure boot and enabled leagacy mode in BIOS. Try ubuntu 16.04 and you will get it to work ! :)

Comment: Which Boot USB creator did you use?

Comment: I have used both unetbootin , dd command i osx , and pen drive linux USB inställer :) all works good :)

Comment: can't get the install to work in Legacy mode. It comes up with an error saying that It's forcing UEFI boot even though it sees that WIn 8 is installed on in Legacy Mode.

Comment: Okey wierd. Well u can try activate UEFI mode and try again :)

Comment: So this still doesn't work.  Win 8.1 is installed in Legacy Mode. So you run the install, it tries to force a UEFI install.

Comment: Ok this worked for me, but I've added a little step: disable fastboot in windows itself as wel (power settings) so windows doesn't save it when you first shutdown windows and startup linux USB.

just so you know: ubuntu 14 and 15 didn't work but I didn't try it anymore after 16 was a succes.